# Polymorphic deserialisation

Tags: java, spring, jackson, deserialization, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to call an API in spring which has two types of the response structure

**Success Response:**

```
{
    "Response": {
        "SubHeader": {
            "requestUUID": "ABC12345678-9x",
            "serviceRequestId": "HI",
            "serviceRequestVersion": "1.0",
            "channelId": "ABC"
        },
        "BodyEncrypted": "OOnpBMVUq6nw/3UesG/L0+lUT0hjOlCYJI064JaAqJvqYYY2bnENE5T/AxOBuoNPUer/W1ioIyDNpj/8cCHzXk5gXF1Cd50gMuGuErlGUogn0Z8hA05q3mygHaf1eb1EiX8qpv1Ke+7I7jw5ds7YsWPuJtXXhhkL0ShrKUimNs0B2OoQxbgH434+JEBvhRa4kcnUvZF68kmgp74k46RUGRbnMUqBEMC5iNMSm0oQgeg="
    }
}
```

**Failure Response:**

```
{
    "httpCode": 403,
    "httpMessage": "Forbidden",
    "errorCode": "B001007",
    "moreInformation": "Unable to fetch details"
}
```

**Feign Client:**

```
fun generateDetails(
            @RequestHeader clientId: String,
            @RequestBody body: RequestDto
    ): ResponseDto
```

Can anyone please help me with how to make **DTO**'s so that the response gets handled for both cases.I tried using **Polymorphism**, but it doesn't seem to work. I am confused about using polymorphic deserialization. Basically, I want to make a general response DTO and handle both the scenario.

Comment: One straight forward way would be to design the DTO with both 'response' and the 'httpCde' etc. Depending on the response, the required attributes shall be populated, which are not present will remain null. You could try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer nested JSON mapping instead of polymorphism. To map nested json values, refer link [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.